# Change image color based on TextBox Focus in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

As shown in the image below I have two times four TextBoxs separated by four images.

What I want to do is when I have Focus on the first Textbox on the right OR the first TextBox on the Left, the first right-left arrow image should change color. When the Focus is lost the color should go back to gray. If the user goes to the second TextBox on the left or right, the second right-left arrow icon should change color and so forth. How can I do this ?

I tried implementing a MultiDataTrigger with IsKeyboardFocusWithin TextBox Property, but could not archive the wanted result. Any suggestions ?

[image: watertextbox]

Here is my XAML code: (the icons are inside the Path property in 2nd StackPanel)

```
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxP1"
                                       WatermarkContent="Parameterausdruck P1" 
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" TabIndex="1"/>

          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxP2"
                                       WatermarkContent="Parameterausdruck P2"                                        
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" TabIndex="3"/>

          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxP3"
                                       WatermarkContent="Parameterausdruck P3"
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" TabIndex="5"/>

          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxP4"
                                       WatermarkContent="Parameterausdruck P4"
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" TabIndex="7"/>

      </StackPanel>

      <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
          <Path Fill="Gray" Margin="5,5,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="11"
                                  Data="F1 M 54,52.0001L 29.25,52.0001L 37.25,60L 26.75,60L 14.75,48.0001L 26.75,36L 37.25,36L 29.25,44.0001L 54,44.0001L 54,52.0001 Z M 22,23.9999L 46.75,23.9999L 38.75,16L 49.25,16L 61.25,27.9999L 49.25,40L 38.75,40L 46.75,31.9999L 22,31.9999L 22,23.9999 Z " />
          <Path Fill="Gray" Margin="5,16,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="11"
                                  Data="F1 M 54,52.0001L 29.25,52.0001L 37.25,60L 26.75,60L 14.75,48.0001L 26.75,36L 37.25,36L 29.25,44.0001L 54,44.0001L 54,52.0001 Z M 22,23.9999L 46.75,23.9999L 38.75,16L 49.25,16L 61.25,27.9999L 49.25,40L 38.75,40L 46.75,31.9999L 22,31.9999L 22,23.9999 Z " />
          <Path Fill="Gray" Margin="5,16,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="11"
                                  Data="F1 M 54,52.0001L 29.25,52.0001L 37.25,60L 26.75,60L 14.75,48.0001L 26.75,36L 37.25,36L 29.25,44.0001L 54,44.0001L 54,52.0001 Z M 22,23.9999L 46.75,23.9999L 38.75,16L 49.25,16L 61.25,27.9999L 49.25,40L 38.75,40L 46.75,31.9999L 22,31.9999L 22,23.9999 Z " />
          <Path Fill="Gray" Margin="5,16,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="11"
                                  Data="F1 M 54,52.0001L 29.25,52.0001L 37.25,60L 26.75,60L 14.75,48.0001L 26.75,36L 37.25,36L 29.25,44.0001L 54,44.0001L 54,52.0001 Z M 22,23.9999L 46.75,23.9999L 38.75,16L 49.25,16L 61.25,27.9999L 49.25,40L 38.75,40L 46.75,31.9999L 22,31.9999L 22,23.9999 Z " />

      </StackPanel>

      <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxDesignP1"
                                       WatermarkContent="Design Wert P1"
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                       TabIndex="2"/>

          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxDesignP2"
                                       WatermarkContent="Design Wert P2"
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                       TabIndex="4"/>

          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxDesignP3"
                                       WatermarkContent="Design Wert P3"
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                       TabIndex="6"/>

          <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Name="WatermarkTextBoxDesignP4"
                                       WatermarkContent="Design Wert P4"
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                                       TabIndex="8"/>

       </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: You want the arrow to turn green (or whatever color) when a particular text box is focused, correct?  Where are those arrows coming from?  I see them on the screen  shot, but no declarations in the code...

Comment: @GeoffOverfield yes they should turn green for example. The images are in <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">  just search for Path, the path are the icons actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using a separate style for every single text box, an other solution would be a simple little behavior. They have the advantages of being re-usable throughout your application and you can add more functionality later. Here's an example:

This class is added to the Path, and bound to a FrameworkElement - FocusElement. Whenever the focus is changed in that element it changes the Fill property. You could add properties for the fill colors if you wanted different ones throughout your application, but I kept it simple - switching between hard-coded orange & gray:

```
public class FocusHighlightBehavior : Behavior<Path>
{
    public FrameworkElement FocusElement
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(FocusElementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FocusElementProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FocusElement.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusElementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FocusElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(FocusHighlightBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, (o,e) =>
        {
            //this is the property changed event for the dependency property!
            (o as FocusHighlightBehavior).UpdateFocusElement();
        }));

    private void UpdateFocusElement()
    {
        if (FocusElement != null)
        {
            FocusElement.GotFocus += FocusElement_GotFocus;
            FocusElement.LostFocus += FocusElement_LostFocus;
        }
    }

    private void FocusElement_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
    }

    private void FocusElement_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Fill = Brushes.Orange;
    }
}
```

It's used by simply adding it to the path's xaml like so:

```
     <Path Fill="Gray" Margin="5,5,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="11" Data="...">
            <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:FocusHighlightBehavior FocusElement="{Binding ElementName=WatermarkTextBoxP1}"/>
            </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Path>
```

Here's it working:

[image]

Note, you need to reference `System.Windows.Interactivity`, and include it in your xaml like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        ....
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Style with two separate separate DataTriggers for each Path element:

```
<Path Margin="5,5,5,0" Stretch="Fill" Width="14" Height="11"
                                  Data="F1 M 54,52.0001L 29.25,52.0001L 37.25,60L 26.75,60L 14.75,48.0001L 26.75,36L 37.25,36L 29.25,44.0001L 54,44.0001L 54,52.0001 Z M 22,23.9999L 46.75,23.9999L 38.75,16L 49.25,16L 61.25,27.9999L 49.25,40L 38.75,40L 46.75,31.9999L 22,31.9999L 22,23.9999 Z ">
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=WatermarkTextBoxP1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=WatermarkTextBoxDesignP1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

Comment: This works very well, how come didn't I think of this. The only problem here is that I have to repeat so many times the style.  That is in every path once. I will wait to see if someone comes up with a better solution otherwise I will accept your answer.